# Rails form lookup details in javascript and post to page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, coffeescript

I'm new to javascript / coffeescript / jQuery, but want to implement the following in my Rails application. What should I look into to get this working?

- When a form's text field is edited, a function is called that then looks up the value in a table and returns the value in a div on the page.

The text field has an id of `personNumber` and I want it to look up the associated name for the value in the `People` table and post it into the page to a div with id `persondetails`.

```
$ -> $("#personNumber").focusout(show_message)
show_message = -> $("#persondetails").html("Name will go here");
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add [a bit of AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to what you already have:

```
$ ->
    $('#personNumber').focusout(show_message)
    show_message = ->
        id = encodeURIComponent($('#personNumber').val())
        $.ajax
            url: '/path/to/your/controller/' + id + '/name'
            type: 'get'
            success: (data) ->
                $('#persondetails').html(data.name)
            error: ->
                # Do something sensible
```

Then you'd route `/path/to/your/controller/:id/name` to a controller method sort of like this:

```
def your_method
    #... look up params[:id] and leave the person in `person`
    if(person)
        render :json => { :name => person.name }, :status => :ok
    else
        render :json => { :msg => 'some error message' }, :status => :not_found
    end
end
```

If you wanted to be able to look up names based on things other than just the ID, you could add some flexibility like this:

```
$ ->
    $('#personNumber').focusout(show_message)
    show_message = ->
        $.ajax
            url: '/path/to/your/controller'
            type: 'get'
            data: { id: $('#personNumber').val() }
            success: (data) ->
                $('#persondetails').html(data.name)
            error: ->
                # Do something sensible
```

Then route `/path/to/your/controller` to a controller method as above and add a bit more logic to `your_method` to be able to find the `person` based on other things that might be `params`.

You might want to add a "loading..." message as well. You could show a "loading..." `<div>` before calling `$.ajax` and hide it in the `complete` callback from `$.ajax`.

Comment: Thanks mu - ill give this a go tonight.